# Custom --config options showing up in "bazel help <command>"

Tags: bazel, bazelrc

If I define a custom --config option in my .bazelrc such as

```
# My custom config
build:my_config --define my_setting=true
build:my_config --define my_other_setting=true
```

is there any way to get this to show up in "bazel help build" or some other command. Preferably with some sort of custom help text. I think this would be a nice feature for keeping track of build options. Especially, due to some projects like tensorflow, wanting to create .bazelrc configs even as an external dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to get this to show up in "bazel help build" or some other command

No, unfortunately Bazel doesn't have a feature like this.